# xserver not using hotplug keyboard and mouse

Tags: linux, xorg, input-device, xinput

I'm using a Linux desktop. My own customized distro, using debian packages, but no `systemd` stuff.

The problem is if I re-plug the USB keyboard or mouse, the X will not respond to them anymore. unless I kill `xinit` process then `startx` again.

Also if I plug a second keyboard or mouse, them will not be used automatically by X.

More information, the `/dev` is handled correctly. Because `dbus-daemon --system` and `/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd` are in the `ps` list. And `evtest` will work correctly on the hot-plug/re-plug mouse or keyboard.

So I think the problem is laying on the part of how the X using these input devices as it's input.
My question is  what software or module doing the absent work?

Any workaround automatically or manually to adding `/dev/input/event*` to be used by X is acceptable.

Thank you.

Comment: Is udevd actually sending the uevents about newly connected devices? Is it applying the proper permissions to the /dev nodes? Being in the process list means not much.

Comment: @user1686 the newly created node permission is for root, I always change them to user manually. and for uevents, how to check them? do you mean uevents need to pass to xorg via dbus?

Comment: Maybe that's the problem then? When udev is in charge of fixing permissions through .rules, it applies those _before_ announcing an uevent to applications that the device is "ready". When you do it manually, that happens well _after_ programs have already received the uevent and tried (unsuccessfully) to access the device. (The uevents are sent via netlink, `udevadm monitor [-p]` will show both the ones sent from kernel to udev, and the ones from udev to general userspace.)

Comment: @user1686 after I add a rule `KERNEL=="event*", OWNER="neoe"`, the hotplug worked. stranger thing is I didnot write for mouse,its `crw------- 1 root root mouse1` but mouse also hotplug enabled. But I still dont know what program is triggered for X. `xinput` is not likely I did not write it.